# How to make a variable a range in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, variables, scripting, range

I am trying to make a variable equal to a range. 
My script includes user input and this input has to fall within a certain range. I will be using the range a couple of times in the script so I want it to be a variable. 
This is what I have tried:

```
    $serverrange = "1..18"
```

and I've tried

```
    $serverrange = 1..18
```

I have googled it but I can't find much about this. The problem is PowerShell doesn't see this as a range, it sees it as 1..18 literally. 
So if I do Write-Output $serverrange it display as "1..18". So my question is how do I get it to see it as a range or how do I change the script to incorporate the range?
Here is the rest of the script:

```
     #user input for how many servers will be tested
     $numofservers = Read-Host -Prompt "How many servers are being tested?"
     if($numofservers -eq $serverrange) {
     "Proceed"
     } 
     else {
     "Server limit exceeded"
      }
```

Edit: Didn't realize that $serverrange = 1..18 worked.

Comment: wrapping the range in quotes makes it a _string_. [*grin*] also, the `Read-Host` cal returns ... a _string_. your 2nd example gives a proper range, try testing the $Variables by using `$VarName.GetType()` to see what is in the variable.

Comment: Which .net type do you have in mind? Does .Net have some 'range' type like some other platforms/languages have?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, thanks for the answer. I didn't realize that the second option was working, my bad. Do you know how I can make the user input display "Proceed" if it falls within this range?

Comment: @techguy1029 - your test is for `$ServerLimit` but i don't see where you set that. if you want to see if `$numofservers` is in the range, force it to an [int] and then use `$numofservers -in $serverrange`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you've since realized, **an *unquoted* expression such as `1..18` works perfectly fine**: it uses **PowerShell's [*range operator* (`..`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) to create an array of contiguous integers** from `1` to `18`; i.e., it is the equivalent of the following array *literal*:

```
 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18
```

By contrast, **`"1..18"` is an (expandable) *string* whose content prints as-is** (literal `1..18`, in this case, because the string contains neither variable references nor subexpressions).

**Important**: While it *technically* works to use **`Invoke-Expression`** to evaluate a *string* as a PowerShell *statement* (e.g., `Invoke-Expression "1..18"`), this approach **should be *avoided***: `Invoke-Expression` is **rarely the right tool** and **presents a *security risk***, particularly with unsanitized user input - see [the PowerShell-team blog post entitled "Invoke-Expression considered harmful"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Your **challenge seems to be create such a range based on *user input***, which is by default a *string*, as returned by `Read-Host`.

The **range operator** is capable of *dynamically* converting either operand (range endpoint) to an integer, and **happily accepts *expressions* as the range endpoints**:

```
1..(Read-Host 'Enter the upper bound')
```

If you enter `3` (which, as stated, is returned as a *string*), PowerShell dynamically converts that string to its integer equivalent and creates array `1..3`, whose default output looks like this:

```
1
2
3
```

That said, in **order to (a) provide user-friendly prompting that (b) enforces a predefined range of inputs (numbers), more work is needed**.

Therefore:

- Ensure that what the user enters can be converted to (a) a *number* that (b) falls within the expected range; if not, prompt again.
- Once valid input has been received, use PowerShell's range operator (`..`) to construct the array of indices, as desired.

```
# Define the implied lower bound and the maximum upper bound.
$lowerBound = 1
$maxUpperBound = 18

# Prompt the user for the upper bound of the range, with validation,
# until a valid value is entered.
do {
  $userInput = Read-Host -Prompt "How many servers are being tested?"
  if (
    ($upperBound = $userInput -as [int]) -and 
    ($upperBound -ge $lowerBound -and $upperBound -le $maxUpperBound)
  ) {
    break # valid value entered, exit loop.
  } else {
    # Invalid input: Warn, and prompt again.
    Write-Warning "'$userInput' is either not a number or is outside the expected range of [$lowerBound,$maxUpperBound]."
  }
} while ($true)

# Create the array of indices based on user input.
1..$upperBound
```

Comment: Yes, I googled what you said and I also want to give more info on why Invoke-Expression isn't very secure. It is interesting. As a new-ish powershell user I had no idea.    https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/why-invoke-expression-is-evil

Comment: So, if `Invoke-Expression` is not the way to go, how would you suggest to handle ranges grabbed from a text file ([example](https://pastebin.com/Yi5SeynY))? Is there an alternative, e.g. `"1..10" -as [???]` or a way to have e.g. `Get-Content` interpret strings as ranges or integers?

Comment: @FatalBulletHit `[int] $from, [int] $to = "1..10" -split '\.\.'; $from..$to`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string "1..18", then you can use [`invoke-expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) to evaluate it, for example:

```
PS C:\Users\chris> $s = "1..18"
PS C:\Users\chris> $s
1..18
PS C:\Users\chris> $r = invoke-expression $s
PS C:\Users\chris> $r
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
PS C:\Users\chris>
```

Comment: Thanks for extra information. How do I get the script to accept the range? If I enter any number in the range besides 1, I get the second message instead of the first one.

Comment: You can use `-contains`, e.g. `$x = "2" ; if (1..18 -contains $x) { "Gotcha" }`.

Comment: While your solution _technically_ works, [Invoke-Expression should be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/): it is rarely the right tool and presents security risks.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
> $p = 1..18
> $p
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
>
```

Using:
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.1944